# Почему я не вижу троеточия в первом тэге <p>, а также переменная g не заменяет текст этого тега?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p id = "text">...</p>

   <script>

var xmlFileGet = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlFileGet.open('GET',"https://epamekids.github.io/README.md", true);
xmlFileGet.send();
alert( xmlFileGet.responseText );
if (xmlFileGet.status != 200) 
   var g = xmlFileGet.status + ': ' + xmlFileGet.statusText;
}
else {
   var g = xmlFileGet.responseText;
}

   </script>

   <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = g'>For printing text</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Потому, что `<p id = "text">...</p>` надо заменить на `<p id="demo">...</p>`. Ну и фигурные скобки в условиях и циклах ставить всегда - нагляднее и меньше вероятность ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Чуть упростил код.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="demo">...</p>

  <script>
    var g;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://epamekids.github.io/README.md', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      g = xhr.responseText;
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  </script>

  <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = g;'>For printing text</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

То же, что @UModeL, но синхронно

Ошибки в коде

- нужно правильно определить переменную `g`
- ошибка, не хватает  `{` в  `if`
- нужно указать что запрос выполнять синхронно -  `false`, `xmlFileGet.open(url, false)`
- неверно указан идентификатор DOM элемента, (text, demo)

Пример с небольшими исправлениями:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p id="text">...</p>

   <script>

var xmlFileGet = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlFileGet.open('GET',"https://epamekids.github.io/README.md", false);

xmlFileGet.send();

console.log(xmlFileGet.status);

if (xmlFileGet.status != 200) {
   g = xmlFileGet.status + ': ' + xmlFileGet.statusText;
}
else {
   g = xmlFileGet.responseText;
}

console.log(g)

   </script>

 <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=g'>For printing text</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```